# How and why do we test BufferPool HIT RATIO graphs

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, buffer

we are testing BufferPool HIT RATIO graphs for DB call that happen through stored procedures (DB2).
Now what I dont understand is "why and how we test them."

When I google about BUFFERPOOL, I got that when pages (in turn our data I guess) is not updated then those pages will be picked from bufferpool else they will be picked from hard disk.

So my questions are :

1. How we test this for  a db call. 
   If I am requesting some data continuously then data might not be changed then how BufferPool HIT RATIO graphs should look like.
2. If the graph is 100 percent or if goes down to 0, then what it mean. Basically how we check that which level in graph is good or bad.
3. On the whole I want to understand the concept of looking at BufferPool HIT RATIO graphs.
4. And which scenario is right for testing this. If my database is not changing then also I can see and compare results as compared to DB which changes frequently.
5. If any one can give some links for this, that also will help.

**Buffer Cache Hit Ratio** shows how SQL Server utilizes buffer cache
“Percent of page requests satisfied by data pages from the buffer pool”
It gives the ratio of the data pages found and read from the SQL Server buffer cache and all data page requests. The pages that are not found in the buffer cache are read from the disk, which is significantly slower and affects performance.
For more info : http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-memory-performance-metrics-part-4-buffer-cache-hit-ratio-page-life-expectancy/

This link solves my questions no : 1,2 & 3.

Now if some one can share there experience for qsn no 4. That would be big help.

Actually we are trying to monitor performance issues that can be caused in actual application's db, by testing our stored procedures in another DB which we use for test /develop purposes.

Comment: Care to tell us what a "bufferpool graph" is?

Comment: I wrote an article about my thoughts of the check_db2_health plugin for Nagios: http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2014/10/how-to-analyse-bufferpool-hit-ratio.html